# Ruby on Rails: PDF.JS ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/pdf js/web/viewer.html"):

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdf.js

I'm using PDF.js in a rails application from https://github.com/shyammohankanojia/pdfjs_rails. I followed the instructions and everything works fine in development, but in production the viewer doesn't show the pdf.

I got the following error: "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/pdf js/web/viewer.html"):".

I'm sure that pdf's are uploaded correctly in production. I ran bundle install and precompiled assets again. In development I didn't have to make any changes to routes.rb.

Any thoughts on how can i get the viewer to show the pdf in production?

Comment: Can you show your production.rb?

Comment: Looks to me there is a space after pdf so correct URL should be "/pdfjs/web/viewer.html. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help, i found that changing this line in production.rb "config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?" for this one "config.serve_static_files = true" will do the trick